# how can i use jfxtra lab icalendaragendaTrial and depended (main class to run outlook like calendar)test classes as a project

Tags: javafx-8, jfxtras

I have cloned jfxtra-lab gradle project from [here](https://github.com/JFXtras/jfxtras-labs) 
I want to use this in new javafx project where i can extend its functionality.
And this is under some **BSD** license .will it be okay to reuse this code.

If you have any idea please advice me.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The license reads:

Redistribution and use in source and binary forms, with or without
modification, are permitted provided that the following conditions are met:
    * Redistributions of source code must retain the above copyright
      notice, this list of conditions and the following disclaimer.
    * Redistributions in binary form must reproduce the above copyright
      notice, this list of conditions and the following disclaimer in the
      documentation and/or other materials provided with the distribution.
    * Neither the name of the  nor the
      names of its contributors may be used to endorse or promote products
      derived from this software without specific prior written permission.

So you can use and modify it. Even better would be to contribute improvements and extensions back to the project, of course.

Comment: thanks @tbeernot  for making the license part clear.